Trying to skip one level when generating Json from wrapper class that contains two classes
So I have this domain class in a spring boot app for a REST API, that contains two subdomain objects:
public class Maximize {

   
    private Profit profit;
   
    private Stats stats;
...

The generated JSON looks like this:
{
    "profit": {
        "request_ids": [
            "id_001",
            "id_003"
        ],
        "total_profit": 88
    },
    "stats": {
        "avg_night": 10,
        "min_night": 8,
        "max_night": 12
    }
}

but I need it to look like this:
{
    "request_ids": [
        "id_001",
        "id_003"
    ],
    "total_profit": 88,
    "avg_night": 10,
    "min_night": 8,
    "max_night": 12
}

So, what I need is to void profit and stats level in json and just print its content
I tried by overriding toString() method of Maximixe class, look around Gson library but I couldn't find an easy or simple way of doing it, any hints?

You should clarify your problem and fix a title because you want to serialise not the object but its properties and it is different than just skipping a property.

Depends on what library you are using. If you are using Jackson you can use the @JsonUnwrapped annotation:
public class Maximize {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Profit profit;
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Stats stats;
...
}


JSON handling in Spring Boot is not like a text editor where you can simply delete lines at your will.
You can

either define a different class for the target object with the structure you want (the proper way), map source to target and then serialize the target or
put everything into a Map<String, Object> with a List<String> for that array. The keys of the map will become the names of the properties. Then serialize the map.

